# Managing Secrets for QA Automation: Local and CI Execution without Paid Solutions for Java based framework

Tags: java, api, framework, software-testing

I'm looking for a robust solution to manage secrets (tokens, clientIds, clientSecrets, passwords) for my QA automation project, with a specific focus on keeping these secrets outside the project repository. I'm particularly interested in a solution that will fit this two aspects:

Local Execution: How can I securely store and access secrets when running tests locally on my development machine?

Continuous Integration (CI) Execution: What's the best approach to handle secrets when my automation tests are executed as part of a CI/CD pipeline?

I want to emphasize that I'd like to avoid paid solutions like AWS Secret Manager and explore open-source or free alternatives.

Comment: Did you try e.g. git-crypt? https://medium.com/@jon_gille/decrypting-secrets-in-your-ci-cd-pipeline-c57da11e1794